# Sorting a list in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

In Orchard CMS, I made custom content type Event which contains an "Even Date" part (this Event Date is actually a widget i installed from the gallery), and after that I made a list of Events.
How can I sort this list by Event Date as I don't have this field in the "order by" select box in the list properties?

Comment: You might have to use the Projection module, which will be released in the upcoming Orchard 1.4 (est. date: end of Feb '12). You can try it out now by getting the 1.x branch of the code.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I thinks that this is the only solution that is currently available, of course, except developing your own module.

Comment: The Mechanics module provides sorting (and a lot of other useful stuff) but is going to get a big update with 1.4 too (afaik, I'm not the developer of Mechanics).